# horizontal listview inside vertical listview in android

Tags: android, listview, horizontallistview

Lazyadapter for listview (vertical) inside this, what i do ,set lazyadapter on horizontal listview & HLV is declare in custom layout of this lazyadapter.

```
class lazyadapter extends BaseAdapter {
    Context context;

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    public lazyadapter(Context context,
            ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> arraylist) {
        this.context = context;
        data = arraylist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
            ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View itemView = inflater
                .inflate(R.layout.horizontal, parent, false);

        HashMap<String, String> mapss;

        mapss = new HashMap<String, String>();

        String dataq = data.get(position).get("subcatname");
        String catname = data.get(position).get("catname");
        String image = data.get(position).get("image");
        String id = data.get(position).get("id");
        mapss.put("dataq", dataq);
        mapss.put("image", image);
        mapss.put("catname", catname);
        mapss.put("id", id);
        TextView uu = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        hlvSimpleList1 = (HorizontalListView) itemView
                .findViewById(R.id.hlvSimpleList1);

        uu.setText(data.get(position).get("catname"));
        String tttt = data.get(position).get("cc");

        if (tttt.equals("1")) {
            uu.setVisibility(0);
            ap = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        } else {
            uu.setVisibility(8);

            hlvSimpleList1.setVisibility(8);

        }
        ap.add(mapss);
        lazyadapter4 adpp = new lazyadapter4(getApplicationContext(), ap);
        adpp.notifyDataSetChanged();
        hlvSimpleList1.setAdapter(adpp);

        return itemView;

    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance..please help me to get rid from this..

Comment: from what do you wanna get rid of your question is not clear

Comment: thanks for reply. i wanna use horizontal listview   inside listview  i do it but in horizontal listview it shows only one item and unable to scroll horizontal listview .

Comment: Have you solved your issue?? If yes then please let me know.

Comment: Yes by useing horizontal listview in row.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

In the Row.xml of the listview (which you will inflate in adapter's getView(..) function) use HorizontalScrollView as Parent element .

Comment: I'm not using horizontal scroll , I'm using horizontal listview. :(

Comment: If you want horizontal and vertical scrolls, please use normal ListView tag and in row use HorizontalScrollView

Comment: yeah dude i'using like this  but in row  it shows only one item.

Comment: I think you must revisit how ListView adapter work: each row makes a listView. Each row will be horizontally scrollable and whole listview vertically

Comment: yes i know but  my problem is that horizontal listview is unable to scroll.